# Expand a file name with a tilde to its fullpath (Common Lisp)

Tags: common-lisp, home-directory, pathname

I have a directory name (as string) with a tilde: `~/projects`.

I want to get its fullpath: `/home/user/projects`. How do I do that ?

The goal is to pass it to `uiop:run-program`, that doesn't seem to do the right thing©.

---

With this answer: [How to translate (make-pathname :directory '(:absolute :home "directoryiwant") into absolute path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16656079/how-to-translate-make-pathname-directory-absolute-home-directoryiwant-i)

```
(merge-pathnames 
          (make-pathname
           :directory '(:relative "~/projects"))
          (user-homedir-pathname))
#P"/home/me/~/projects/"
```

=> WRONG

Thank you.

---

**edit** I'll share more context.

I wanted to run a program through `uiop:launch-program`. I had a user-defined list of directories such as `~/projects`. Using it as is created the `./~/projects` directory instead of `/home/user/projects`.

`truename` doesn't work if the directory doesn't exist.

On SBCL, `(namestring "~/doesntexist")` returns also its tilde.

`merge-pathnames` didn't work, still the tilde problem.

Feeding `ensure-directories-exist` with this result created a directory named `~`.

Given the answers, I had no choice but to adapt the logic to expand the directory name of a directory we actually want to exist.

```
;; Create a directory
;; Ensure its name (string) ends with a slash.
(setf mydir
        (str:concat (string-right-trim (list #\/) mydir)
                    "/"))
(ensure-directories-exist base)
```

Then I could use its `truename`.

Comment: Note that this isn't CL-specific at all; tildes are *generally* expected to be expanded before a path leaves the user's interactive, POSIX-compliant shell and is handled by applications. No standard UNIX tool does tilde expansion -- if you run `rm '~/foo.txt'`, it'll look for a file in a directory named `~` -- so it's generally expected that applications just won't *try* to put this in-scope.

Comment: A good reminder!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a native-namestring function in uiop, which should be available in all implementations:

```
(uiop:native-namestring "~/projects")
=> /home/user/projects
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! It also works with a directory name that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 6):

### General remarks about ~

Your Lisp implementation may or may not support tilde syntax.

If it does (e.g. CCL, ABCL, CLISP, ECL, LispWorks), then `truename` would consistently expand to a filename:

```
(truename "~/projects")
 => /home/user/projects
```

If your implementation doesn't, or if you want to code portably, you have to merge relatively to `(user-homedir-pathname)`:

```
(truename (merge-pathnames #p"projects" (user-homedir-pathname)))
 => /home/user/projects
```

Note that the tilde, if it is supported, seems to only be supported for strings used as pathnames, and not in directory components; `(:relative "~")` does not work as you would expect, and refers to a directory literaly named "~".

Instead, at least for SBCL, the appropriate directory is `(:absolute :home)`, or, if you want to refer to another user, you can wrap the component in a list:

```
(make-pathname :directory '(:absolute (:home "root")))
=> #P"~root/"
```

Notice how it only works if the `:home` form is just after `:absolute`, it doesn't work otherwise (see [Home Directory Specifiers](https://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Home-Directory-Specifiers)).

### Expanding to non-existent pathnames

> `truename` would require that the thing exists?

Yes, if you want to build the absolute path to a file that does not exist (yet), then you need to call `truename` on the part that exists, and merge with that.
In your case, that would be `(truename "~/")`, which is the same as `(user-homedir-pathname)`.

As pointed out by Rainer Joswig, calling `namestring` on implementations other than SBCL returns an expanded pathname, translating `~` as `/home/user`. In SBCL you have to call `sb-ext:native-namestring` to obtain the same effect.

In other words, in order to expand to a filename that does not necessarily exist, you could write the following portability layer:

```
(defun expand-file-name (pathname)
  (check-type pathname pathname)
  (block nil
    #+(or lispworks clozure cmu clisp ccl armedbear ecl)
    (return (namestring pathname))
    #+sbcl
    (return (native-namestring pathname))
    #+(not (or sbcl lispworks clozure cmu clisp ccl armedbear ecl))
    (let ((expanded (namestring pathname)))
      (prog1 expanded
        (assert (not find #\~ expanded) () 
                 "Tilde not supported")))))
```

See also https://github.com/xach/tilde/blob/master/tilde.lisp for inspiration if your Lisp doesn't support the syntax.

Comment: `truename` would require that the thing exists?

Comment: Yes it does, `truename` fails if the directory doesn't exist. I'd enjoy a solution that supports this.

Comment: @RainerJoswig Yes, it seems there is no portable way to resolve a pathname if it does not exist, but `truename` can still be called on the parts that are expected to exist.

Comment: `namestring` would work in many implementations which understand `~`: CCL, ABCL, CLISP, ECL, LispWorks. SBCL returns the tilde name...

Comment: Issue opened in SBCL: https://bugs.launchpad.net/sbcl/+bug/1853833

Answer (score 0):

Anselm Farber's solution, involving uiop:native-namestring breaks on some pathnames that don't have native-namestrings, like the following:

```
(uiop:native-namestring "~/Music/[Video] performance.mp4")
==>
The pathname #P"~/Music/[Video] performance.mp4"
does not have a native namestring because
of the :NAME component #<SB-IMPL::PATTERN (:CHARACTER-SET
                                           . "Video")
                                          " performance">.
   [Condition of type SB-KERNEL:NO-NATIVE-NAMESTRING-ERROR]
```

Here is a direct solution that only uses pathname- functions:

```
(defun expand-user-homedir (f)
  (let ((d (pathname-directory f)))
    (if (and (eql (car d) :absolute)
             (eql (cadr d) :home))
        (make-pathname :directory (append (pathname-directory (user-homedir-pathname))
                                          (cddr d)) 
                       :name (pathname-name f) 
                       :type (pathname-type f))
        f)))
```